# XML to CSV in PYTHON: Extract series of subnodes for every node

Tags: python, xml, loops, csv, nodes

My goal is to convert an .XML file into a .CSV file.
This part of the code is already functional.

However, I also want to extract the sub-sub-nodes of one of the "father" nodes.

Maybe an example would be more self explanatory;

Here is the structure of my XML:

```
<nedisCatalogue>
   <headerInfo>
    <feedVersion>1-0</feedVersion>
    <dateCreated>2018-01-22T23:37:01+0100</dateCreated>
    <supplier>Nedis_BENED</supplier>
    <locale>nl_BE</locale>
   </headerInfo>
   <productList>
    <product>
     <nedisPartnr><![CDATA[VS-150/63BA]]></nedisPartnr>
     <nedisArtlid>17005</nedisArtlid>
     <vendorPartnr><![CDATA[TONFREQ-ELKOS / BIPOL 150, 5390]]></vendorPartnr>
     <brand><![CDATA[Visaton]]></brand>
     <EAN>4007540053905</EAN>
     <intrastatCode>8532220000</intrastatCode>
     <UNSPSC>52161514</UNSPSC>
     <headerText><![CDATA[Crossover Foil capacitor]]></headerText>
     <internetText><![CDATA[Bipolaire elco met een ruwe folie en een zeer goede prijs/kwaliteits-verhouding voor de bouw van cross-overs. 63 Vdc, 10% tolerantie.]]></internetText>
     <generalText><![CDATA[Dimensions 16 x 35 mm    
    ]]></generalText>
  <images>
   <image type="2" order="15">767736.JPG</image>
  </images>
  <attachments>
  </attachments>
  <categories>
   <tree name="Internet_Tree_ISHP">
    <entry depth="001" id="1067858"><![CDATA[Audio]]></entry>
    <entry depth="002" id="1067945"><![CDATA[Speakers]]></entry>
    <entry depth="003" id="1068470"><![CDATA[Accessoires]]></entry>
   </tree>
  </categories>
  <properties>
   <property id="360" multiplierID="" unitID="" valueID=""><![CDATA[...]]></property>
  </properties>
     <status>
      <code status="NORMAL"></code>
     </status>
     <packaging quantity="1" weight="8"></packaging>
     <introductionDate>2015-10-26</introductionDate>
     <serialnumberKeeping>N</serialnumberKeeping>
     <priceLevels>
          <normalPricing from="2017-02-13" to="2018-01-23">
       <price level="1" moq="1" currency="EUR">2.48</price>
      </normalPricing>
      <specialOfferPricing></specialOfferPricing>
     <goingPriceInclVAT currency="EUR" quantity="1">3.99</goingPriceInclVAT>
     </priceLevels>
     <tax>
     </tax>
     <stock>
      <inStockLocal>25</inStockLocal>
      <inStockCentral>25</inStockCentral>
      <ATP>
       <nextExpectedStockDateLocal></nextExpectedStockDateLocal>
       <nextExpectedStockDateCentral></nextExpectedStockDateCentral>
      </ATP>
     </stock>
    </product>
  ....
</nedisCatalogue>
```

And here is the code that I have now:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse("/Users/BE07861/Documents/nedis_catalog_2018-01-23_nl_BE_32191_v1-0_xml")
root = tree.getroot()

f = open('/Users/BE07861/Documents/test2.csv', 'w')

csvwriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter='ç')

count = 0

head = ['Nedis Part Number', 'Nedis Article ID', 'Vendor Part Number', 'Brand', 'EAN', 'Header text', 'Internet Text', 'General Text', 'categories']
prdlist = root[1]
prdct = prdlist[5]
cat = prdct[12]
tree1=cat[0]

csvwriter.writerow(head)

for time in prdlist.findall('product'):
    row = []
    nedis_number = time.find('nedisPartnr').text
    row.append(nedis_number)
    nedis_art_id = time.find('nedisArtlid').text
    row.append(nedis_art_id)
    vendor_part_nbr = time.find('vendorPartnr').text
    row.append(vendor_part_nbr)
    Brand = time.find('brand').text
    row.append(Brand)
    ean = time.find('EAN').text
    row.append(ean)
    header_text = time.find('headerText').text
    row.append(header_text)
    internet_text = time.find('internetText').text
    row.append(internet_text)
    general_text = time.find('generalText').text
    row.append(general_text)
    categ = time.find('categories').find('tree').find('entry').text
    row.append(categ)
    csvwriter.writerow(row)

f.close()
```

If you run the code, you'll see that I only retrieve the first "entry" of the categories/tree; which is normal. However, I don't know how to create a loop that, for every node "categories", creates new columns such as categories1, categories2 & categories3 with the values: "entry".

My result should look like this

```
Nedis Part Number   Nedis Article ID         Vendor Part Number   
VS-150/63BA         17005              TONFREQ-ELKOS / BIPOL 150, 5390  


Brand     EAN           Header text               Internet Text 
Visaton   4,00754E+12   Crossover Foil capacitor  Bipolaire elco …



General Text              Category1    Categroy2     Category3
Dimensions 16 x 35 mm     Audio        Speakers      Accessoires
```

I've really tried my best but didn't manage to find the solution.

Any help would be very much appreciated!!! :)

Thanks a lot,

Allan

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
for child in time.find('categories').find('tree'):
    categ = child.text
    row.append(categ)
```

Here's a solution that loops through the xml once to figure out how many headers to add, adds the headers, and then loops through each product's category list:

**Updated to iterate through images in addition to categories. This is the biggest difference:

```
for child in time.find('categories').find('tree'):
    categ = child.text
    row.append(categ)
    curcat += 1

while curcat < maxcat:
    row.append('')
    curcat += 1
```

It's going to figure out the maximum number of categories on a single record and then and that many columns. If a particular record has less categories, this code will stick blank values in as placeholders so the column headers always line up with the data.

For instance:

```
Cat1     Cat2     Cat3     Img1     Img2     Img3
A        B        C        1        2        3
D        E        <blank>  4        <blank>  <blank>
```

Here's the full solution:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse("c:\\python\\xml.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

f = open('c:\\python\\xml.csv', 'w')

csvwriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')

count = 0

head = ['Nedis Part Number', 'Nedis Article ID', 'Vendor Part Number', 'Brand', 'EAN', 'Header text', 'Internet Text', 'General Text']
prdlist = root[1]

maxcat = 0
for time in prdlist.findall('product'):
    cur = 0
    for child in time.find('categories').find('tree'):
        cur += 1
    if cur > maxcat:
        maxcat = cur

for cnt in range (0, maxcat):
    head.append('Category ' + str(cnt + 1))

maximg = 0
for time in prdlist.findall('product'):
    cur = 0
    for child in time.find('images'):
        cur += 1
    if cur > maximg:
        maximg = cur

for cnt in range(0, maximg):
    head.append('Image ' + str(cnt + 1))

csvwriter.writerow(head)

for time in prdlist.findall('product'):
    row = []
    nedis_number = time.find('nedisPartnr').text
    row.append(nedis_number)
    nedis_art_id = time.find('nedisArtlid').text
    row.append(nedis_art_id)
    vendor_part_nbr = time.find('vendorPartnr').text
    row.append(vendor_part_nbr)
    Brand = time.find('brand').text
    row.append(Brand)
    ean = time.find('EAN').text
    row.append(ean)
    header_text = time.find('headerText').text
    row.append(header_text)
    internet_text = time.find('internetText').text
    row.append(internet_text)
    general_text = time.find('generalText').text
    row.append(general_text)

    curcat = 0

    for child in time.find('categories').find('tree'):
        categ = child.text
        row.append(categ)
        curcat += 1

    while curcat < maxcat:
        row.append('')
        curcat += 1

    curimg = 0

    for img in time.find('images'):
        image = img.text
        row.append(image)
        curimg += 1

    while curimg < maximg:
        row.append('')
        curimg += 1

    csvwriter.writerow(row)

f.close()
```

Comment: Now suppose that I want to do the same for "images", assuming images can also have multiple sub node "image"; how could I do that? I'm very sorry but I starting in Python.. :( Thank you so much